# Trusted applications for API

Tags: php, android, authentication

everyone know that, android application can be decoded and everyone can see how looks code of application.

We must create api for application like groupon in PHP, api will be used to communicate with other applications, like android or objective-c or another PHP applications. We are wondering, how to protect api. API can be used only for trusted applikations, so when we'll created app in android, and someone decode our app and create the same app, our API will be doesn's work.

How works applications like facebook, google+, groupon, which must login using propably api.

I will be greatfull for Yours answers and advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the following

[OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/)

[Android Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

This will help you solve the problem you have.

Also checkout the [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) which show you an example of how this is done on the android. You will have to implement a suitable api part.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, but it's not exacly what I want. For example, I will be have in PHP API link like this: http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=somethink and I will be getting all offers from my app, like groupon, and I want to dissallow getting affers to another applications. Someone could decode my application, and create the same, but it will be not my application yet.